# How to select only highlighted occurences of a word?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If you put your cursor on a word, VSC will highlight all standalone occurences (i.e. not substrings) of that word, yet `Ctrl-D` will select any occurence of the word, even if it's a substring of another word. How do I prevent this behavior?

For example, putting your cursor on `pkt` and using the above shortcut will result in `pkt_new` being selected as well.

```
pkt_t *pkt = pkt_new();
if (pkt == NULL) {
    abort();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Command: `toggleFindWholeWord`

Default keybinding: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

#### Edit:

From version [1.18 (Oct 2017)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_ctrld-cmdd-improvements) `select word` was separated from search widget and now always selects whole word (if no text is selected).